# Filter UDP packet in tc filter

Tags: udp, filter, tc

Hello I'm trying to limiting the bandwidth on my `iperf` udp test (`iperf -u`). I use `tc qdisc` and class to make some assured rate and ceiling rate for it. However, I don't know what filter I should use to limit the UDP performance? I tried several matching criteria like:

```
$ sudo tc filter add dev $DEV parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip src 10.0.0.1 match ip protocol 17 0xffff flowid 1:20
$ sudo tc filter add dev $DEV parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip src 10.0.0.1 match ip protocol 17 0xff flowid 1:20
$ sudo tc filter add dev $DEV parent 1: prio 1 u32 match udp src 10.0.0.1 flowid 1:20
```

But none of them work. I tried many times but it seems the UDP `iperf` (`iperf -s -u` and `iperf -c -u ip`) result stays the same which is 1.05 Mbps.

Does anyone know how to filter the UDP the right way?

Comment: If you are using SNAT on this machine, the matching is done after SNAT and thus the rule never see 10.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

`tc-filter` shapes traffic of sent control packets and can not control received packets. So, when you use udp, `iperf` doesn't need a reply, the speeds stays the same. When you use tcp, `iperf` needs an ack, so it works... I guess.